# IIS rewrite rule. Can't get it to work. It gives 'redirect multiple times' error

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to redirect the user every time he enters subdomain.mywebsite.com to subdomain.mywebsite.com/app
I tried to do the following

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^subdomain.mywebsite.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/app" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it gives me 'redirect multiple times' error
Please advice

UPD: I also need it to work for https

```
https://subdomain.mywebsite.com
```

So every time the user opens subdomain.mywebsite.com with HTTP or HTTPS it should forward to `https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/app`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your rule also works for https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/. So it keep redirecting to itself.
Please add a condition pattern {HTTPS}=off to only redirect http request.

```
  <rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^subdomain.mywebsite.com$" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/app" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

5/7Edit:
Please try this rule

```
        <rule name="MyRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^subdomain.mywebsite.com$" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/app" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="My Rule2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^app(/)?$" negate="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^subdomain.mywebsite.com$" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/app" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="MyRule3" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^subdomain.mywebsite.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://subdomain.mywebsite.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: @vily I added another rule to redirect https request.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Also, I am hosting in Azure and it has a setting 'Only HTTPS'. Does it mean that I don't need to use HTTP rule?

Comment: Just checked. It worked, but couldn't render the page anymore. I have an angular application under /app and now it gives this http://i.piccy.info/i9/363b666da8a57fadbdef3fcd35c661f8/1588596067/18313/1376442/Annotation_2020_05_04_153712.png

Comment: @vily If you are hosting angular application in IIS, please remember to add  condition pattern  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> to your rule. Otherwise, all source files will be redirected to /app.

Comment: Added but it didnt work. Now it doesn't redirect anymore

Comment: What about revmove  "is not a directory"?

Comment: It redirects again, but then shows Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in the console

Comment: If I just remove any rewrite logic from Web.config and run https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/app, it works good.

Comment: @vily did you see any 404 error in developer tool->network tab?

Comment: No, I only see Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: This is network tab http://i.piccy.info/i9/aec6308ed64321aab47f60b29e744b88/1588783204/177128/1376442/2.jpg

Comment: I think I know what's the problem. existing file and directory shouldn't be redirect to /app. You only have to redirect http file &directory to https. Then redirect non-exist file/directory to /app.

Comment: @vily I just update the sample rules. Please check if it achieve your requirement.

Comment: No, it doesn't redirect this time. And also the same JSON error. Do you wanna call me and I will share my screen?